# How do I make a Statusbar notification that does nothing and goes nowhere?

Tags: android, notifications

I have a working statusbar notification for Android already, but to create it I must set an Activity for it to open. I don't want *any* activity to open; however, this small project doesn't need an interface at all.

```
mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) aContext
        .getApplicationContext().getSystemService(
                Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

// Create the pending intent, which is basically NOW.
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent
        .getActivity(aContext, 1, new Intent(aContext, BlankActivity.class),
                PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

// Create notification
notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(aContext)
        .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher) // required for launch
        .setTicker("Downloading video...") // required for launch
        .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis()) // should be set for now.
        .setContent(remoteView);
```

`BlankActivity` is what it sounds like -- an activity that has no content and closes upon being opened. But it still shows up on the list of recently opened windows. I cannot set this to null.

Is there a way I can avoid setting an intent for the status notification at all?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need `PendingIntent` in that case. Just setting it `null` in `setContentIntent()`  might help.

Another way can be

```
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(aContext(),0,new Intent(),PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
```

Try this.

Comment: Okay, you nailed it in your example; it works perfectly. Thank you. I haven't tested the "null PendingIntent" suggestion yet.

Answer (score 1):

Setting it to null does not work for early versions like SDK 2.3 which requires an intent to be set, otherwise android will choke at receiver's start with the exception:`java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.movistar.android.mimovistar.widgets.WidgetIntentReceiver: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: contentIntent required`
[see this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21317792/receiver-throws-illegalargument-exception)